# Character by character reading the input from JEditorPane in Java

Tags: swing, jtextarea, jeditorpane, html-editor

I am trying to create an Html Editor. For this I am using JEditorPane, in which I want to read input from the JEditorPane character by character and want them to be stored in a string. For example: if user types `<h` so I want to read those two characters and according to those characters I will suggest users for the tags, in this case `<html>,<header>,<head>` etc (i.e. all tags starting with 'h'). So I am not getting how and which function to use to read character from JEditorPane as soon as user inputs into the JEditorPane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So I am not getting how and which function to use to read character from JEditorPane as soon as user inputs into the JEditorPane.

You can use a `DocumentListener` Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for more information and examples.

If you are creating an editor, which just displays the text, not the actual formatting, then you should use a JTextArea or a JTextPane. A JEditorPane is really only for displaying existing HTML files.

Answer (score 0):

Keylistener worked for me. Using keylistener we can get input key strokes by the user.

Comment: Don't use a KeyListener. KeyListeners are used on old AWT applications. Swing has newer and better API's . In this case Swing was designed to be used with a DocumentListener. You can still get the character input in to the text area or text pane from the DocumentEvent.